# as3 and admob/adsense, whatever ad in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, ads

Hi I have made an app in flash as3, air for android and I want to add some ads I thought that I could use admob, but i'm a very noob in coding and such so I don't know what to do, I have written all kind of things googled the whole web but I can't figure out how to use ads in as3 does someone know??

Comment: First result on Google: [Using the AdMob Adobe AIR native extension for Android](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/admob-ane-android.html).

Comment: @poke yeah but I don't want to pay 29.99 sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a native extension for this. There are several out there but if you're not willing to pay you might want to look into creating your own. Though the time you spend on that might out way the cost.

Here's the documentation to the one I've been involved with developing:

http://docs.airnativeextensions.com/adverts/docs/

You can find it here:

http://distriqt.com/native-extensions

If you're going to make your own, you'll want to start here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/index.html

And the AdMob documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the work as you ,I know how to add admob to flash air ios and flash air android application. but I get some error( [how to add google admob ad in flash for ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561223/how-to-add-google-admob-ad-in-flash-for-ios) ) when I try to,maybe you can have a try to test if there is the same error.